# jQuery clone input table with latest user inputs

Tags: jquery

I am trying to re-use an input table. My idea is to save the final state of an input table using `jquery` and then add it to the output page. However, my code only saves the default inputs, which means any changes made by user will not be saved. So any suggestions on this issue? For example, how to let the drop-down input element save user selection using jquery (I have about 100 input elements, so it will be nice if the code is very generic). Thanks!

HTML code:

```
<table class="tab">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="3" scope="col">
            <label for="id_nott">No. of Time-Varing Factors:</label>
        </th>
        <td colspan="1" scope="col">
            <select name="nott" id="id_nott">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input class="submit input_button" type="button" value="Click" />
```

jQuery:

```
$("input[value='Click']").click(function () {
    var html_input = $(".tab").clone().html();
    console.log(html_input)
})
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qAh4D/1/)

Comment: what result do you expect to get?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What ever you set for the dropdown goes as a part of the element property which will not be visible in the html.

Comment: clone() does not clone the value properties, you have to get those yourself, or set the attributes manually before cloning.

Comment: @RubenKazumov: I am trying to make a copy the final state of the input table

Comment: @PSL: I am trying to save user inputs in jQuery and then post them in an output page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qAh4D/4/)

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/ -- simple way to get and deliver state of your inputs, but you have to wrap html in `form` tag.

```
$("input[value='Click']").click(function (){
    $("form").on( "submit", function (event){
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log($(this).serialize());
    });    
});
```

output:

```
nott=2
```

*recommendation:*

Try to use a conventional naming for `id` and `name` attributes.

Comment: Thanks! But how to get the latest html form as well (not only the name and values, but also those <td>, <tr>)

Comment: you have to know, select/option change will not reflect on html code at all. its just a state and it is reflected in memory. you have no "save" the visual state. however, you can create attribute "`selected`" in clone code by regex later. but it will be "another" code, because native code have not `selected` attribute. YOU MUST: send html, send serialization and reconstruct the state by variable values.

Comment: It seems like there is no shortcut on this issue. Thanks.